Checking if arrays within arrays are empty using PHP
I have the following array and need to essentially check if there are any values in it using PHP.
Array (
    [amazon_uk] => Array(
        [retailer_link_or_sku] => 
        [affiliate_url] => 
    )
    [awd_it] => Array(
        [retailer_link_or_sku] => 
        [affiliate_url] => 
    )
    [ccl_online] => Array(
        [retailer_link_or_sku] => 
        [affiliate_url] => 
    )
)

So for example I would like the above array to return empty because none of the [retailer_link_or_sku] or [affiliate_url] array keys have values.
However, I'd expect the following array to return not empty because a couple of the keys have "value123" there:
Array (
    [amazon_uk] => Array(
        [retailer_link_or_sku] => value123
        [affiliate_url] => 
    )
    [awd_it] => Array(
        [retailer_link_or_sku] => 
        [affiliate_url] => 
    )
    [ccl_online] => Array(
        [retailer_link_or_sku] => value123
        [affiliate_url] => 
    )
)

I've tried (empty($array)), (!array_filter($array)), sizeof($array) but I think because inside the main array there are values e.g. [amazon_uk] & [awd_it] & [ccl_online], they're all returning as not empty even though none of them have values themselves.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Split this. One part is writing code for the inner part, one is for the outer.

You can use recursion to iterate over all entries. As soon a value is set, return true.
$arrayWithValues = [
    'amazon_uk'  => [
        'retailer_link_or_sku' => 'value123',
        'affiliate_url'        => ''
    ],
    'awd_it'     => [
        'retailer_link_or_sku' => '',
        'affiliate_url'        => ''
    ],
    'ccl_online' => [
        'retailer_link_or_sku' => 'value123',
        'affiliate_url'        => ''
    ]
];

$arrayWithoutValues = [
    'amazon_uk'  => [
        'retailer_link_or_sku' => '',
        'affiliate_url'        => ''
    ],
    'awd_it'     => [
        'retailer_link_or_sku' => '',
        'affiliate_url'        => ''
    ],
    'ccl_online' => [
        'retailer_link_or_sku' => '',
        'affiliate_url'        => ''
    ]
];

function hasValue(array $array): bool
{
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (hasValue($value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        elseif ('' !== $value) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump(hasValue($arrayWithValues));     // true
var_dump(hasValue($arrayWithoutValues));  // false

